# Is it possible to use Data URI image to set a post thumbnail?

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

I have a custom template I am setting up on a site that generates an image in canvas to go along with the post in Data URI format, and allows me to save it as jpg/png. However, would like these images to be set as the featured image when publishing the post.

I think it may be possible with set_post_thumbnail(), however, I am at a loss after working on it for a few days.